# Xamarin Forms (iOS) - share cookies between application login and Microsoft PowerApp

Tags: authentication, xamarin, cookies, xamarin.forms, powerapps-canvas

Currently I'm trying to create an App in Xamarin Forms that shares its login session (logging-in with Microsoft) with a webview that contains a Microsoft PowerApp (as my application, it uses Microsoft account to login).

I just created a custom webview and a custom webview render. In Android custom render I used  `Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptThirdPartyCookies(Control, true);` to accept third party cookies and it works well.
But I'm having trouble with iOS where I couldn't find a similar way to accept third party cookies and I can't go through it. I've already tried to use `NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;` but it didn't work for me.

I'm not using Xamarin in a long time, so any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

S.

Comment: `sharedCookieStorageForGroupContainerIdentifier`  is the actual thing that can do the job of sharing Cookies across apps for us. If you plan to share Cookies across apps or app extensions, you might want to use this or plan to use this as part of your design. Check https://medium.com/@mahithegeek/sharing-cookies-in-ios-nshttpcookiestorage-part-2-ee466c17e96